# Getting actor position with its padding

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I want to get the position of the actor inside InputListener. The problem is that however I get the correct position it is not including the pad of the actor. How can I get this?

```
    // MenuBar class extends Table
    defualts().pad(5.0f);
    Label label = new Label(name, labelStyle);
    add(label);
    menuGroup.setup(label)
```

---

```
    // MenuGroup class
    public void setup(Actor actor) {
        actor.addListener(changeListener)
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
            private Vector2 pos = new Vector2();
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            pos.set(0, 0);
            pos = actor.localToStageCoordinates(pos);
            mainMenu.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
            show();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the actor is inside **Table** (and here you should be when your class extending the table) you can just cast its parent and then get pad value. For example to get left pad value you just use:

```
    float padLeft = ( (Table) actor.getParent() ).getPadLeft();
```

Then you can get all pads arround (top,left,bottom,right) and modify the position with it which will give you the position with pad included.

**Remember that position is calculated as position of left-bottom corner** of the actor so you will need just left and bottom pad value.